# Trying to recover files and programs after Windows update

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, data-recovery

I tried to carry out a Windows 10 software update but when I came to restart my laptop, it would not work and kept restarting indefinitely. Eventually, I had to reinstall Windows 10 using a USB but it seems that most of my files and programs were deleted. At least that's what it looked like but upon further inspection, it seems that my C drive (hard drive) and D drive (SSD) have very similar layouts and folders. They both contain the following folders: PerfLogs, Program Files, Program Files (x86), Users and Windows. However, it seems that only the versions of these folders on my D drive are what I am looking for as they are the same as my files and programs before Windows crashed. How can I make it such that I can recover those files and programs and have them being used as the primary rather than those folders in the C drive. I can of course transfer everything manually which is fine for documents but the main problem is that this doesn't recover all the programs I had installed and when I reinstall them, they do not seem to be using the program data from the D drive and is just like a new install.

Things I have tried :

- using recovery software and reinstalling the programs I used before - program data not being applied
- using File history for backup - no File History to use
- using Windows.old - only present in C Drive and no files are showing despite the fact that properties says that there are 57 files and 8 folders present but I cannot see them for some reason (I have ensured that I can view hidden files)
- changing user - I thought maybe there was a different user with all my programs and files but that doesn't seem to be the case

What is the easiest way for me to retrieve the the same state as I had prior to Windows crashing (especially finding a way to have the programs I had previously with the same program data)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I had some important files/programs that I have failed to back up and need them quite soon. Thank you

Comment: There is no way to do what you want, I hope you have  backups of your important data.

Comment: @Moab Hi, I have backups of the files but I am more concerned about all the program settings and data I have lost. Is there no way to get that back based on the data in my D drive?

Comment: You might be able to recover individual files, but even if you recreate the program file directory structure you're still missing all of the registry keys and links that tells Windows how to use those files.

Comment: Sounds like you didn’t reinstall Windows on the correct disk.

Comment: @Brady ah I see what you're saying. Thanks

Comment: @Ramhound can I move Windows onto another disk? And if I can, do you think it'll work then?

Comment: Can you image a HDD with Windows on it, absolutely, can you cut and paste Windows to another disk and expect it to boot absolutely not

Comment: @Ramhound what about if I try to install Windows from USB again but put on the D disk directly, any chance that would work?

Comment: You have to determine which drive your booting from before I could answer that question